# Не работает блок "Поделиться" корректно

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Вставила блок на странице сайта http://www.superkot.ru/articles/pamyatki/vakcinaciya.html
Код:

```
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>

<div class="ya-share2" data-counter="" data-description="Подробно о схемах вакцинации котят в нашем питомнике, а так же о правилах вакцинации взрослых животных." data-image="http://www.superkot.ru/images/articles/vakcinaciya/purevax.jpg" data-services="collections,vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus,twitter,blogger,linkedin,lj,qzone,viber,whatsapp,skype,telegram"></div>
```

При попытке поделиться через Facebook, выводится не корректная картинка и описание блока. Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 1):

Для нормально работы кнопок "Поделится" вы должны установить и правильно настроить поддержку OpenGraph, можете прочитать тут https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Open_Graph_protocol.
Насколько понятно, ваш сайт на CMS Joomla! - вы можете использовать уже готовые плагины, как например https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/bt-social-sharing

Answer (score 0):

Arsen, на странице есть все теги для поддержки Open Graph.
Можно посмотреть на странице http://www.superkot.ru/cat/b10bruno.html.
Картинка все равно не подгружается.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.superkot.ru/components/com_mtree/img/listings/m/503.jpg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Wonder-Plush Bruno" />  
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Питомник британских кошек superkot.ru">
<meta property="og:type" content="котенок">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.superkot.ru/cat/b10bruno.html">
<meta property="og:description" content="Wonder-Plush Bruno">
```

Comment: А Arsen, это о ко или о чём?

Comment: Это автор совета про OG.